# C# asp.net widget with postback defaults to login even with web.config excluding it. Work arounds?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an input widget "subscribeContact.aspx" I have written in c#, asp.net.
It is excluded from authorization with an entry in "web.config". It defaults to displaying the login page. If the screen is refreshed (e.g. F5), the widget appears without the necessity of logging in.

The routine "WebinarDisplay.aspx" also includes a postback function, but does not display the same behavior.

web.config entry:

```
  <location path="~/subscribeContact.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="~/WebinarDisplay.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

The source for the page is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="subscribeContact.aspx.cs" Inherits="SchedulerServices.subscribeContact" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="inputDiv" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="allFieldsRequired" runat="server" Text="All Fields are Required." Visible="true"  Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="selectedFieldsRequired" runat="server" Text="Fields Marked in red are Required." Visible="false"  Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="firstNameLabel" runat="server" Text="First Name" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="firstNameBox" runat="server" Font-Size="Small"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lastNameLabel" runat="server" Text="Last Name" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="lastNameBox" runat="server" Font-Size="Small"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="emailLabel" runat="server" Text="Email Address" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="emailAddressBox" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="phoneNumberLabel" runat="server" Text="Phone Number" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="phoneNumberBox" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" TextMode="Phone"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="stateLabel" runat="server" Text="State" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="stateDDL" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Select a state" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="AL" Text="Alabama" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="AK" Text="Alaska" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="AZ" Text="Arizona" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="AR" Text="Arkansas" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="CA" Text="California" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="CO" Text="Colorado" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="CT" Text="Connecticut" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="DE" Text="Delaware" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="DC" Text="District of Columbia" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="FL" Text="Florida" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="GA" Text="Georgia" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="HI" Text="Hawaii" ></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="ID" Text="Idaho" ></asp:ListItem>  
            <asp:ListItem Value="IL" Text="Illinois" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="IN" Text="Indiana" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="IA" Text="Iowa" ></asp:ListItem>   
            <asp:ListItem Value="KS" Text="Kansas" ></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="KY" Text="Kentucky" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="LA" Text="Louisiana" ></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="ME" Text="Maine" ></asp:ListItem>  
            <asp:ListItem Value="MD" Text="Maryland" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="MA" Text="Massachusetts" ></asp:ListItem>       
            <asp:ListItem Value="MI" Text="Michigan" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="MN" Text="Minnesota" ></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="MS" Text="Mississippi" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="MO" Text="Missouri" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="MT" Text="Montana" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="NE" Text="Nebraska" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="NV" Text="Nevada" ></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="NH" Text="New Hampshire" ></asp:ListItem>       
            <asp:ListItem Value="NJ" Text="New Jersey" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="NM" Text="New Mexico" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="NY" Text="New York" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="NC" Text="North Carolina" ></asp:ListItem>      
            <asp:ListItem Value="ND" Text="North Dakota" ></asp:ListItem>        
            <asp:ListItem Value="OH" Text="Ohio" ></asp:ListItem>   
            <asp:ListItem Value="OK" Text="Oklahoma" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="OR" Text="Oregon" ></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="PA" Text="Pennsylvania" ></asp:ListItem>        
            <asp:ListItem Value="RI" Text="Rhode Island" ></asp:ListItem>        
            <asp:ListItem Value="SC" Text="South Carolina" ></asp:ListItem>      
            <asp:ListItem Value="SD" Text="South Dakota" ></asp:ListItem>        
            <asp:ListItem Value="TN" Text="Tennessee" ></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="TX" Text="Texas" ></asp:ListItem>  
            <asp:ListItem Value="UT" Text="Utah" ></asp:ListItem>   
            <asp:ListItem Value="VT" Text="Vermont" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="VA" Text="Virginia" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="WA" Text="Washington" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="WV" Text="West Virginia" ></asp:ListItem>       
            <asp:ListItem Value="WI" Text="Wisconsin" ></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="WY" Text="Wyoming" ></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="timeZoneLabel" runat="server" Text="Time Zone" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="timezoneDDL" runat="server" Font-Size="Small">
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Select a state" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="HI" Text="Hawaii" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="AK" Text="Alaska" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="PST" Text="Pacific" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Arizona" Text="Arizona" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="MST" Text="Mountian" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="CST" Text="Central" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="EST" Text="Eastern" ></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="resumeLabel" runat="server" Text="Resume" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="resumeBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="50" Rows="15"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitButton_onClick"> </asp:Button>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="thankYouDiv" runat="server">
            <h1>Thank You</h1>
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code behind is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;


namespace SchedulerServices
{
    public partial class subscribeContact : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void submitButton_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // test that fields are filled in
            string xrefID = Request.QueryString["XR"];
            bool sendBack = false;
            firstNameLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstNameBox.Text.ToString()))
            {
                firstNameLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                firstNameBox.Focus();
                sendBack = true;
            }
            lastNameLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastNameBox.Text.ToString()))
            {
                lastNameLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lastNameBox.Focus();
                sendBack = true;
            }
            emailLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailAddressBox.Text.ToString()))
            {
                emailLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                emailAddressBox.Focus();
                sendBack = true;
            }
            phoneNumberLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumberBox.Text.ToString()))
            {
                phoneNumberLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                phoneNumberBox.Focus();
                sendBack = true;
            }
            stateLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            if (stateDDL.SelectedValue == "")
            {
                stateLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                stateDDL.Focus();
                sendBack = true;
            }
            timeZoneLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            if (timezoneDDL.SelectedValue == "")
            {
                timeZoneLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                timezoneDDL.Focus();
                sendBack = true;
            }
            resumeLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resumeBox.Text.ToString()))
            {
                resumeLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                resumeBox.Focus();
                sendBack = true;
            }
            if (sendBack)
            {
                allFieldsRequired.Visible = false;
                selectedFieldsRequired.Visible = true;
                return;
            }
            // get the account ID and User ID
            // put the information in a record layout
            // write record
            inputDiv.Visible = false;
            thankYouDiv.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I am stumped on this one. The other stand alone pages work without a problem, including using code that exists in non-excluded areas. Once the page loads, then it operates as it should.

Comment: Does it only redirect after the user submits or on the inital page load?

Comment: Redirects on pageload.Try this http://tucsonbdg.schedulerservices.com/subscribeContact.aspx

Comment: does it have to be anonymous users or could you allow all users like <allow users="*" /> The page loads once after ive been redirected to the login page and I have a cookie set so I'm no longer anonymous.

Comment: Ok, here is the latest ... It will load and display on a refresh of the page. e.g. execute the widget and it will push to the login page. Re-execute it a second time on the same page, and the page renders (albeit a weirdness with the dropdowns being disabled)?!?!  For an example of code in page (as a widget), go to http://tucsonbdg.com an scroll to the end of the first article. The logon is displayed. Refresh the page (f5) and the page shows up.

Comment: Just tried it with "*" and same behavior

Comment: Also tried it as "?,*" for anonymous and all users. Same results.

Comment: I also moved it into a folder "Public" and set it up for access to all. The same behavior is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that postback will execute the login.aspx regardless of the web.config exclusion.

The answer lies in modifying the login.aspx.cs file to include the following code in the Page_Load section:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string returnURL = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnURL))
    {
// Test for the exclusion
    if (returnURL.Length > 7)
        {
            if (returnURL.Substring(1, 7) == "Webinar")  // or whatever you want to continue on to processing
            {
                Response.Redirect(returnURL);
            }
            if (returnURL.Substring(1, 9) == "subscribe")  // or whatever you want to continue on to processing
            {
                Response.Redirect(returnURL);
            }
        }
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect(returnURL);  // this exists to allow users to re-log in if the session has not timed out
        }
    }
    RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);  // use this if you want the person directed to a registration page
    ResendEmailHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Resend.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);  // use this if you want the person to have the registration email resent to them
    ResetHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "ResetPassword.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);  // use this to allow the user to reset their password
}
```

This now works. So the work around is to code the Login.asp.cs (or whatever is your login page) to specifically redirect to the value in ReturnURL. I re-discovered my workaround when tracing the process and saw the work-around I created 4+ years ago.

I hope this help anyone else stuck with figuring out how to code a widget using straight C#, ASP.NET code without having to resort to more exotic work-arounds using JSON, JQUERY, or MVC